# Report Packages in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, documentation-generation

What is the difference between the stereotype "master document" and "report package" in Enterprise Architect?  I will be generating a document from multiple model documents and I want to organize them better to mimic the structure of the resulting document.  I thought creating "report packages" would do this for me, but whenever I go to generate a document from the "master document" it does not go into the "report packages" and run the model documents contained.

Comment: Which version of EA are you using?

Comment: @MartinGrégoire 13, but I'm still wondering what additional functionality a report package has over the deprecated master document.

Comment: I have updated my answer following Geert's Comment, what's weird is that report packages provide less functionality. I have my thoughts on why that is, but this is not the place for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master Documents are deprecated as of Version 12.1. [Source](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/report_generation/virtualdocuments.html)
The main difference with Report Packages being that Report Packages do not have the RTFTemplate TaggedValue.
Otherwise they function the same.

I suggest on using Report Packages as Master Documents are being deprecated.

To produce virtual documents, create a report package and place your model documents in them
Assign a template to each of your model documents(in the taggedvalues)
The order in which your Model documents generate is the order in which they appear in the Project Browser

Once your report package is complete you can right-click it to generate documentation, you don't need to change the template(Model Report) to generate it

Virtual documents documentation(EA13):
http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/model_publishing/virtualdocuments.html

Comment: Where do you get the information that Master Documents have been deprecated? I can't seem to find that information, nor do I find the difference between the two.

Comment: There is a small mention to Master Documents been deprecated in the 12.1 official documentation [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/report_generation/virtualdocuments.html) (at the end of the document elements row)

Comment: The difference is the RTF Template taggedValue is not in the report package anymore. This taggedvalue on the MasterDocument allowed tospecify headers and footers for the whole document. I do not know why this has been changed

Comment: Weird, I've been using Master Documents up until now without any adverse effects, and I've never used the tagged value RTF template on the master document anyway. I guess I better switch to using Report Packages instead of Master Documents. What a weird strategy to create another thing that is almost 100% the same thing and then deprecate the first one; most annoying.